# Python Install pyrit error, command gcc in CentOS

Tags: python, centos, centos6

I don't can install , this all code in console don't work compiling !! s.o in centos 6 32 bits -- run and later , I have dependencies python with python-dev, tools, etc. 
But I don't know, if you lack another

pyrit

python setup.py build

```
svn: '.' is not a working copy
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'cpyrit._cpyrit_cpu' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.o -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -DVERSION="0.4.0"
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.o: Permission denied
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:35:26: error: openssl/hmac.h: No such file or directory
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:36:25: error: openssl/sha.h: No such file or directory
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:37:18: error: pcap.h: No such file or directory
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:58: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘SHA_CTX’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:98: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘pcap_t’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:210: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘SHA_CTX’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c: In function ‘padlock_xsha1_prepare’:
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:238: error: ‘output’ undeclared (first use in this function)
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:238: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:238: error: for each function it appears in.)
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c: At top level:
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:249: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c: In function ‘prepare_pmk_padlock’:
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:286: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘ctx_ipad’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:286: error: too many arguments to function ‘padlock_xsha1_prepare’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:289: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘ctx_opad’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:289: error: too many arguments to function ‘padlock_xsha1_prepare’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:292: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘HMAC’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:292: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘EVP_sha1’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:292: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘e1’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:295: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘e2’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c: In function ‘finalize_pmk_padlock’:
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:304: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘e1’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:305: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘e2’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:308: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘padlock_xsha1_finalize’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:308: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘ctx_ipad’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:309: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘ctx_opad’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:311: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘e1’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:313: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘ctx_ipad’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:314: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘ctx_opad’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:316: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘e2’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c: In function ‘finalize_pmk_sse2’:
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:352: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘ctx_ipad’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:353: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘ctx_ipad’
    .............................. ... and more ................
 cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:368: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘e1’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:369: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘e2’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:396: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘e1’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:397: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘e2’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c: In function ‘prepare_pmk_openssl’:
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:422: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SHA1_Init’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:422: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘ctx_ipad’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:423: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SHA1_Update’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:423: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘ctx_ipad’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:430: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘e1’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:433: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘e2’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c: In function ‘finalize_pmk_openssl’:
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:440: error: ‘SHA_CTX’ undeclared (first use in this function)
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:440: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘ctx’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:443: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘e1’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:444: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘e2’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:447: error: ‘ctx’ undeclared (first use in this function)
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:447: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘ctx_ipad’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:449: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SHA1_Final’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:451: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘ctx_opad’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:456: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘e1’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:458: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘ctx_ipad’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:462: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘ctx_opad’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:467: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘e2’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c: In function ‘CPUDevice_solve’:
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:543: error: ‘struct pmk_ctr’ has no member named ‘e1’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c: In function ‘fourwise_md5hmac_openssl’:
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:834: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘EVP_md5’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c: In function ‘PcapDevice_init’:
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1384: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘p’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1385: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘status’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1385: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘datalink’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c: In function ‘PcapDevice_dealloc’:
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1396: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘p’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1396: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘status’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1397: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pcap_close’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1397: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘p’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c: In function ‘PcapDevice_close’:
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1407: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘status’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1408: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘p’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1409: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘status’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c: In function ‘PcapDevice_setup’:
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1420: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘datalink’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1420: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pcap_datalink’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1420: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘p’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1422: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pcap_datalink_val_to_name’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1422: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘datalink’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1450: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘status’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c: In function ‘PcapDevice_open_live’:
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1461: error: ‘PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1467: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘status’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1473: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘p’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1473: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pcap_open_live’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1474: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘p’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1461: warning: unused variable ‘errbuf’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c: In function ‘PcapDevice_open_offline’:
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1493: error: ‘PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1499: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘status’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1505: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘p’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1505: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pcap_open_offline’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1506: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘p’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1493: warning: unused variable ‘errbuf’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c: In function ‘PcapDevice_read’:
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1530: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘status’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1539: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pcap_next_ex’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1539: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘p’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1549: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1559: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1560: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1578: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pcap_geterr’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1578: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘p’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c: In function ‘PcapDevice_send’:
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1598: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘status’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1620: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pcap_sendpacket’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1620: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘p’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1622: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘p’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c: In function ‘PcapDevice_set_filter’:
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1639: error: storage size of ‘fp’ isn’t known
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1645: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘status’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1651: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pcap_compile’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1651: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘p’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1653: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘p’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1657: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pcap_setfilter’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1657: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘p’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1659: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘p’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1660: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pcap_freecode’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1639: warning: unused variable ‘fp’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c: At top level:
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:1957: error: ‘PcapDevice’ has no member named ‘datalink’
cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c:2179: fatal error: error closing -: Broken pipe
compilation terminated.
The bug is not reproducible, so it is likely a hardware or OS problem.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

any idea? thanks for help.

Comment: Why are you compiling as root?

Comment: however less root , don't compiling :(

Comment: `export LC_MESSAGES=en_US` and try again please, and post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `openssl-devel` and `libpcap-devel` packages; use `yum` to install them. Also, remove `build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/` before trying again.

Comment: 6 -o build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.so
running build_scripts
creating build/scripts-2.6
copying and adjusting pyrit -> build/scripts-2.6
changing mode of build/scripts-2.6/pyrit from 664 to 775 <<< perfect!! thanks

Comment: but run in console "[opmeitle@localhost]# pyrit -bash: pyrit: no se encontró la orden" because. it's solution run in root.